# How can I find the program I'm hiding in bash

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, path

Say I have `PATH="home/bob/bin:/usr/bin"`.  I am writing a bash script `/home/bob/bin/foo` that will do some munging and then call `/usr/bin/foo`.  Of course I want to be able to use this script on different systems which have different path structures.  In practice the real foo might be in many different places, so I want to just find it from the PATH.  My new foo script is on my path too, so I can't just call foo, that will result in a recursive call.

Is there an easy way of doing this in a bash script? (Other than looping through elements of PATH and doing the search manually?)

Comment: Remove your script's directory from PATH? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path

Comment: @muru Not a good solution if the “real” `foo` might in turn invoke other commands, some of which may be in the same directory as the `foo` wrapper.

Comment: @Gilles; is it realistic to assume a system's global `/usr/bin/foo` is accessing "private" commands like `/home/bob/bin/foo`? - At best that appears to me to be a misdesign.

Comment: @Janis I very very often run `/bin/sh` with the expectation that it runs “private” commands. Or run programs in `/usr/bin` that invoke an editor which is `~/bin/EDITOR`. Etc.

Comment: @Gilles; what you write in the last comment is different from what we have here in your first comment of the question context; i.e. that scripts in the systems context **depend** on scripts in private context. (Nevermind, it was anyway only a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @Janis: I presume you understand what this question is about: a user who wants to “wrap” a system command with a customization that tweaks the operation of the system command.  The classic, well known, trivial example is `alias mv="mv -i"`.  More complicated examples need to be done in shell functions or scripts.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Now, I believe that you’re misinterpreting/twisting Gilles’s comment.  He didn’t say that a system program might **depend** on a private program.  But consider, (on my system, at least) `/bin/ps2html` is a script that runs `gs` (Ghostscript) without specifying a path.  Suppose I have wrapped `/bin/gs` with a front-end `~/bin/gs`.  If I have `~/bin` before `/bin` in my search PATH, then, when I run `/bin/ps2html`, I probably want it to run `~/bin/gs` (which will probably invoke `/bin/gs` with a tweak) — even/especially if I am running `/bin/ps2html` from a `~/bin/ps2html` front-end.

Comment: @Gilles: if the “real” `foo` might in turn invoke other commands, some of which may be in the same directory as the `foo` wrapper, then change PATH ***without exporting it***, so, when `~/bin/foo` says “`foo`”, it will get `/usr/bin/foo`, but, when `/usr/bin/foo` says “`bar`”, it will use the *original* `$PATH`, which it gets from the environment, and so it can find `~/bin/bar`.

Comment: @G-Man You can't change the value a variable without exporting it in Bourne-style shells. Either a variable is exported, and the environment variable has the same value as the shell variable, or it is not exported, and the variable is not present in the environment.

Comment: @Gilles: Dang; I misread something.

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the path to the second `foo` with:

```
foo=$(type -Pa foo | tail -n+2 | head -n1)
```

(provided file paths don't contain newline characters).

Beware that may be a relative path which would stop to be valid after you run `cd`.

You could then do:

```
hash -p "$foo" foo
```

So *that* `foo` be invoked when you run `foo`.

Comment: You're assuming that `foo` is being executed through the PATH. This has the potential to recurse if it's executed with an explicit PATH and there's one other `foo` in front.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easier way to do this robustly than enumerating the directories in `PATH`. It isn't hard.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f; IFS=:
for d in $PATH; do
  if [[ -f $d/foo && -x $d/foo && ! $d/foo -ef /home/bob/bin/foo ]]; then
    exec "$d/foo" "$@"
    exit 126
  fi
done
echo "$0: foo (real) not found in PATH"
exit 127
```

I assume there are no empty entries in PATH. Empty PATH entries are evil, write `.` explicitly (or better don't include it at all).

If you'll only ever run `foo` from the command line and not from other programs, make it a function instead of a script. From the function, run `command foo` to hide the function.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, shouldn't it be `exec $d/foo "$@"`?

Answer (score 0):

If foo is important, then it should be configured in the script. This I think is good practice, because you then EXPLICITLY peg it to the script. I do not like indirection, implicit or hidden stuff ... scripts should be very simple if they are to be deployed.

Otherwise if you insist on finding it, then it can be found by doing

```
whereisfoo="$(which foo)"
```

If this is not enough, then I fear what you may be doing is too complex.

Comment: But the OP has a script called `foo` in has private bin directory (`$HOME/bin`), which appears at the beginning of his `$PATH`, so `which foo` will report `/home/bob/bin/foo` — which is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: I think it is bad practice to hide stuff in scripts. It only gets you into trouble. Making the user stumble if a configuration file is not set is better practice

Comment: (1) “… hide stuff in scripts”?  What?  I wonder whether you understand the question.  (2) “configuration file”?  Where did that come from?  (3) “[S]cripts should be very simple if they are to be deployed.”  OK, that’s your opinion, which (3a) doesn’t really help answer this question, and (3b) is, I suspect, a minority opinion.  Albert Einstein is credited with saying “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.”  A script (or any other piece of software) should be as complicated as it needs to be to satisfy its requirements.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And (I’m not sure whether this is 3c or 4) you say scripts should be very simple, but that a script that executes a `mv` command should be distributed with a configuration file that tells it whether `mv` is in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`?  Seriously?

Comment: I do not think he is doing 'just' an mv. He is doing some munging and then calls /user/bin/foo ... Since /user/bin/foo may be somewhere else he needs to find it. I see this as bad design (my opinion). Because foo is a dependency that must be implicitly found (unbeknownst to the user).

Comment: This question is about a user who wants to “wrap” a system command with a customization that tweaks the operation of the system command.  The classic, well known, trivial example is `alias mv="mv -i"`.  More complicated examples need to be done in shell functions or scripts.  Are you saying that `alias mv="mv -i"` is bad design?  For that matter, if I write a script called `do_stuff` that uses commands like `mv`, `cp`, and `ls`, then the shell (that runs that script) needs to find those programs.  Is that bad design?  I don’t understand your argument.

Comment: You know very well I am not saying that. What I am saying is that burying a dependency and having to discover it (through some script trickery) is not elegant nor wise.

Yes it is possible ... but that is not the way to go. Entry and exit conditions as well as dependencies should be known to the end user if he is DEPLOYING it - As he stated in his/her post.

Comment: I ***do not "know very well"*** what you are and are not saying.  I still do not understand the difference between `~/bin/do_stuff` running `mv` and expecting to get `/bin/mv`, versus `~/bin/mv` running `mv` and expecting to get `/bin/mv`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an approach that I believe is 
slightly less messy than Gilles’ answer
(although I concede that to be a subjective judgment).

```
#!/bin/sh
this_dir=$(dirname "$0")        # Alternatively, hard-code this as this_dir=$HOME/bin
redacted_PATH=$(echo ":${PATH}:" | sed -e "s:\:$this_dir\::\::" -e "s/^://" -e 's/:$//')
if obscured_prog=$(PATH=$redacted_PATH which foo)
then
            ⋮           # Munging to do before running /usr/bin/foo
        "$(obscured_prog)" argument(s)          # may be "$@", but might not be.
            ⋮           # Munging to do after running /usr/bin/foo
else
        echo "$0: foo (real) not found in PATH."
            ⋮           # Any code that you want to do anyway.
fi
```

This constructs `redacted_PATH` to be `$PATH`
minus the `$HOME/bin` directory where this private copy of `foo` lives. 
`echo ":${PATH}:"` adds colons to the beginning and end of `$PATH`,
so every component of it will be preceded and followed by a colon —
even the first and last one.  The `sed` searches for

```
: $this_dir :
```

(with spaces added for “clarity”) and replaces it with

```
:
```

i.e., it excises `$this_dir` from `":${PATH}:"`. 
It then removes the colons from the beginning and end.

Then we temporarily set `PATH` to `$redacted_PATH`
and search for `foo` using `which`. 
If successful, we get a full path to it (e.g., `/bin/foo` or `/usr/bin/foo`),
which we use to run the real (public/shared/system) copy of `foo`. 
Since we changed `PATH` only temporarily,
`/bin/foo` has access to the user’s ambient `$PATH`,
and so, if `/bin/foo` runs `brillig`, it can find `$HOME/bin/brillig`
(if it exists).

This will have a problem if `$HOME/bin` appears in `$PATH` multiple times,
but that’s not too hard to remedy.