# Modified PATH without /usr/bin

Tags: path

How can I save a modified `PATH` in `PATH_MOD` that does not contain `/usr/bin`?

Output of `PATH`:

```
/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @roaima tried it with sed, but found no solution

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108873/117549

Comment: MakeReal, please [show us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/589237/edit) in your question how you "_tried it with `sed`_". It might be that you're almost there and fixing your attempt would be better for your learning than providing a completely different solution

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: 
`PATH_MOD=$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:\/usr\/bin:/:/g')`

EDIT:
double \ in order to make backslashes visible

Comment: That wouldn't work if `/usr/bin` was first or last in `$PATH` or if there were 2 consecutive `/usr/bin` (as in `PATH=/x:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/y`)

Comment: That would also potentially not work properly if `$PATH` contained `$IFS` characters or wildcards or backslashes or was something like `-Ennen`...

Answer (score 0):

In the `zsh` shell:

```
path=("${path[@]:#/usr/bin}")
```

updates `$PATH` in place. Or to set `$PATH_MOD` instead:

```
PATH_MOD=${(j[:])path:#/usr/bin}
```

In `zsh`, `$PATH` is tied to the `$path` array (like in `(t)csh`) and `${array:#pattern}` expands to the elements of the array that don't match the pattern.

Beware that if `$PATH` was just `/usr/bin`, then it becomes empty. For `zsh`, that means there's no command to be found anywhere, but for most of everything else, that means *the current working directory* is looked for for commands!

The equivalent in `bash` 4.4+ could be done using some helper function like:

```
remove_element() {
  local - text=$1 IFS=$2 element=$3 i
  set -o noglob
  set -- $text""
  for i do
    if [ "$i" != "$element" ]; then
       set -- "$@" "$i"
    fi
    shift
  done
  REPLY="$*"
}

remove_element "$PATH" : /usr/bin
PATH_MOD=$REPLY
```