# Remove paths from $PATH variable with PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e ...) doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, path

Because I'm not familiar with the way to add permanent path, I export the wrong dir accidently, which is  **/home/adolph/anaconda3/condabin**. (It should be /home/adolph/anaconda3/bin)

```
adolph@adolph-System-Product-Name:~$ echo $PATH
/home/adolph/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/adolph/anaconda3/bin:/home/adolph/anaconda3/bin
```

I tried to remove the wrong directory in the method introduced by most of the post.
[reference1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path?newreg=470817cde3624230b2eb22b9c74eb90a&newreg=912792b2ef404b0ea1e9ffd6b1b9ce7e)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650840/remove-redundant-paths-from-path-variable)

```
adolph@adolph-System-Product-Name:~$  PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/home\/adolph\/anaconda3\/condabin$//')
```

However, it still exist. How to solve it in effective way?

```
adolph@adolph-System-Product-Name:~$ echo $PATH
/home/adolph/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/adolph/anaconda3/bin:/home/adolph/anaconda3/bin
```

Comment: How exactly did you "add permanent path"? I see little value in modifying it programatically - just correct what you did and start a new shell. (BTW the reason your `sed` fails is that `:\/home\/adolph\/anaconda3\/condabin$` only matches a *trailing* path component.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your desired PATH  for your current session like this:
`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/adolph/anaconda3/bin`
If you want that change to be permanent, you could add that line to your `~/.bashrc`.